# Linux user/permission management with multiple servers

Tags: security, ubuntu

I work with a team that manages about 15 linux (Ubuntu) servers and we are looking for a way to manage the users and their permissions more efficiently.  Right now, we don't have a clear idea of what users are enabled on any given server, unless we login and check it out.  In addition to this, it's hard to change passwords (because one user has an account on multiple servers) or lock them out.

Are there any tools that will allow us to add/edit/delete users and their groups across multiple servers?  I want to keep everything in sync, without running active directory.

Comment: LDAP?  open ldap is a good one for ldap. http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsysm/article.php/3088441/Building-an-LDAP-Server-on-Linux-Part-1.htm

Comment: Brian - This is perfect.  Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP would be a good use case

[open ldap](http://www.openldap.org/) is a good one for ldap.

Here is a resource for this http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsysm/article.php/3088441/Building-an-LDAP-Server-on-Linux-Part-1.htm

Comment: Ubuntu - and I read yesterday that this was already included by default!

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian Thomas said, you may want to setup an LDAP server. OpenLDAP would accomplish everything you want to do in this post, and an easy to use web interface can be installed to make the whole process easier.

IIRC, OpenLDAP comes pre-installed on Ubuntu servers, so all you need to do is configure it.

Comment: Thank you - I am going that route.  I am voting your answer up, but I will ask Brian to post the answer and accept it since he posted first. Thanks again for the information!

Comment: A perfectly reasonable action, thanks for the vote up!